# mongodb ~ sorted distinct list / does distinct have sort()?

Tags: mongodb

This doesn't, nor 100 variations, work.

```
db.getCollection('countryCodesAndSubCodes')
 .distinct( 'Cn', {enabled: true} )
 .sort( { Cn: 1 } );
```

> Type error ({ Cn: 1 }) is not a function

but this does:

```
db.getCollection('countryCodesAndSubCodes').distinct( 'Cn', {enabled: true} );
```

and this too:

```
db.getCollection('countryCodesAndSubCodes').find({}).sort( { Cn: 1 } );
```

So how do you sort a distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.getCollection('countryCodesAndSubCodes').distinct( 'Cn', {enabled: true} )` returns a plain old javascript array (assuming a String array, but it doesn't really matter).

To sort it just call `sort()`

Or more specifically:

`db.getCollection('countryCodesAndSubCodes').distinct( 'Cn', {enabled: true} ).sort()`

Whereas `db.getCollection('countryCodesAndSubCodes').find({}).sort( { Cn: 1 } );` does a cursor sort (as opposed to the array sort).

For a cursor sort you need a sort key and direction `{ Cn: 1 }`

Comment: so find, which also returns a plane old javascript array does something differently with sort.  I also tried `.sort(function(a,b) { return a.Cn < b.Cn }); // < just to prove the point`  but doesn't have any effect.  I have to through the output of .distinct() into a variable before .sort() is actually useful.

Comment: `find()` returns a cursor, not an array. You can call `toArray()` on it in order to transform it to array